# Recurring: object in the query API

Tags: quire-api

Where I can find the full list of possible values for the "data:" property in the recurring object?

The only thing that is stated in the API documentation is:

> If weekly, bit 0 is Sunday, bit 1 is Monday and so on. For example, if the data is 6, it means every Monday and Tuesday.

It would be nice to know all the possible values for monthly, yearly and custom recurring.

Answer (score 0):

quire Github project just added a documentation task about that topic. It contains information for the current existing types:
https://github.com/quire-api/quire-api/issues/54